# Masking raster with a multipolygon

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, geopandas, rasterio

I have a .tiff and a multipolygon as a .shp. Both have been exported from QGIS using the same CRS (EPSG:3857).

I load in the shapefile using `GeoPandas` and the TIFF using `Rasterio`. Then want to use the .shp to create mask the raster using `rasterio.mask.mask` like the following:

```
geo = gpd.read_file("label.shp")
print(geo.crs)

with rasterio.open("image.tif") as src:
  print(src.crs)
  out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, geo.geometry, filled = True)
```

This gives me an output:

```
epsg:3857
EPSG:3857
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasterio/mask.py:88: UserWarning: shapes are outside bounds of raster. Are they in different coordinate reference systems?
  warnings.warn('shapes are outside bounds of raster.
```

When plotting the mask layer it is empty.

I don't understand why my shapes are outside the bounds since the CRS are the same. I've tried using `.to_crs` so that the shapefile and raster are the same CRS, just to double check, but this doesnt add anything.

I thought this would be straightforward, is there anything I'm overlooking? Does a multipolygon need to be handled differently?

Comment: `print(src.bounds)` and `print(geo.bounds)` or at least *some* details about the actual locations of the data should be included in your question as an edit, as you have not provided enough info to answer your question. They can be in the same CRS and outside the bounds if they don't actually overlap each other. Have you overlaid them visually to ensure the polys do overlap the raster?

Comment: EPSG 3857 bounds are -180.0 -85.06 180.0 85.06 whereas EPSG 4326 bounds are -180.0 -90.0 180.0 90.0
If when converting to EPSG 3857, you did not crop your vector layer to it bounds, you may have shapes outside of the bounds hence the error

Comment: Using command line,  crop your shp with `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" output.shp inout.shp -clipsrc -180.0 -85.06 180.0 85.06`

Comment: @ThomasG77 the "bounds" in the error message refers to the bounds of the data. not the bounds of the CRS.  i.e [this situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfSdT.png) where the bounds of both datasets are well within the CRS bounds.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my side. Thanks for clarification. Never too late to learn ;). Sorry Ellio for the "noise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is:

> `UserWarning: shapes are outside bounds of raster. Are they in different coordinate reference systems?`

This is telling you that the bounding box of your multipolygon dataset does not overlap the bounds of your raster.  It is not telling you it is outside the bounds of the CRS or that the datasets are in different CRSs. The datasets being in different CRSs is just one way of generating this warning, another is that the data simply don't overlap like the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856)'s answer and to reassure you of your method, your code works fine on a raster and multipolygon that actually intersect. I would then tend to agree that it is not the CRS that it is the problem, it is likely the location of your polygons.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio import mask
from rasterio.plot import show

rast_path = r"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\mask\raster.tif"
mask_path = r"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\mask\mask.shp"

geo = gpd.read_file(mask_path)
print(geo.crs)

with rasterio.open(rast_path) as src:
  print(src.crs)
  out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, geo.geometry, filled = True)

show(out_image)
```

[image: result.png]

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to directly convert the out_image to a tif? ty

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66393086/4227297) is what you need.